# How to get the number of threads executing current method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to debug performance issues in multithreaded code and I'm wondering if there's a way to print out the number of threads currently executing the method. For example, suppose I have the following:

```
public void concurrentMethod(Object data) {
    int numberOfThreadsExecutingThisMethodSimulataneously = //...?
    System.out.println(numberOfThreadsExecutingThisMethodSimulataneously);
    //method body...
}
```

Specifically, I am using a ThreadPoolExecutor, so jobs are being submitted as follows:

```
ExecutorService executor;
for (Object data : myData) {
    executor.execute(() -> concurrentMethod(data));
}
```

Comment: What is that for? Maybe a simple log inside the method printing `Thread.currentThread()` could be enough.

Comment: You can keep a static set and add thread names there in the beginning of the method and remove at the end.

Comment: Is the thread pool bounded?  The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) provides some stat methods, and discusses hook methods so perhaps use an AtomicInteger to track.

Comment: @AndrewS The thread pool is bounded (corePool and maxPool are same size). Also my example is a simplificaiton - in practice the method I'm calling is called from another method in another class, and has no knowledge of the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
static AtomicInteger currentNumberOfThreads = new AtomicInteger();
public void concurrentMethod(Object data) {
  currentNumberOfThreads.incrementAndGet();
  try {
    // currentNumberOfThreads.gets() 
  } finally {
    currentNumberOfThreads.decrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Spring, this would be a job for an Aspect.

Comment: Just to clarify: so I should call something like `System.out.println(currentNumberOfThreads.incrementAndGet());` in the first line of the method and call `currentNumberOfThreads.decrementAndGet();` at the last line?

Comment: @SinaMadani yes